# PowerBi Matrix conditional formatting for one column only

Tags: powerbi

I have this matrix

[image: matrix]

The three matrix columns are the sum of value "N" sorted by the "Type" column (so in the type columns there are "C", "EN" and "TO DO" types who are here the matrix columns). I want to give a conditional formatting only for the "TO DO" type. The two other types should stay white. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a measure that returns the background colour you need when the Type is TO DO:

```
Format = 
  VAR st = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Type])
  VAR val = SUM('Table'[N])

  RETURN IF(st = "TO DO", IF(val >1000, "#750000", "#12AF00"))
```

And then use it in the CF:
[image]